Is the method subscribe in angular 17 is not working
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Substitua 'your-endpoint' pelo seu endpoint real
    this.apiService.getData('your-endpoint').subscribe(
      response => {
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data', error);
      }
    );
  }
}

The subscribe method appears crossed out.

I'm not on that version, but generally when something is crossed out it's deprecated meaning that it still works but is not the current way and may get removed in the future. What type does getData return?

This return is not the correct way, I believe it is due to the fact that the HttpClientModule is obsolete, so ProvideClientHttp was used instead, but apparently the methods are not the same. And I have no idea what the new ones look like.

This question is similar to: Subscribe is deprecated: Use an observer instead of an error callback. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The comma separated method of passing next, error and complete callback is deprecated.
.subscribe((data: any) => {}, (err: any) => {}, () => {}); // <- deprecated! 

Try an object with next, error and complete properties, this syntax is not deprecated.
this.apiService.getData('your-endpoint').subscribe({
      next: response => {
        this.data = response;
        console.log(this.data);
      },
      error: error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data', error);
      }
});

